# Hibernate wrongly tries to insert dependency on persist

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have an entity to be persisted with another entity as dependency in a many-to-one relationship. The dependent entity is always loaded from the EntityManager when constructing instances of the entity to be persisted. However, when I try to persist the entity, Hibernate attempts an insert on the dependency as well, resulting in an error. Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can disable it?

The entity is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="postal_code")
public class PostalCode implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    PostalCodePK id;

    @MapsId("country")
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="country")
    private Country country;

    public PostalCode(Country country, String code) {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

The dependent entity Country is defined as follows:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="code_alpha2", columnDefinition="bpchar")
    @Size(min=2, max=2)
    private String codeAlpha2;

    ...
}
```

The relevant code for constructing and persisting the entity is:

```
PostalCode postalCode = new PostalCode(em.find(Country.class, "DE"), "01234");
em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(postalCode);
em.flush();
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

The log-output when I invoke persist on an instance of PostalCode is then:

```
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Country
        (code_alpha3, code_alpha2) 
    values
        (?, ?)
Aug 05, 2013 11:40:59 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23505
Aug 05, 2013 11:40:59 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "country_pkey"
  Detail: Key (code_alpha2)=(DE) already exists.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem as you, and this is what I did to solve it.

```
  @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
  @JoinColumn(name = "equityId", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private Equity equity;
```

The key here is, the FetchType being EAGER and cascade REFRESH. Because FetchType is lazy by default, for some reason its not initialized and its null, as a result hibernate thinks its empty and tries to insert the object when you set it. If you fetch it eagerly, there will be an object that it can update instead.

(You might be able to get away with another cascade type, but this is what worked for me)